# Python: Equidistant points along a line joining set of points

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

As numpy.linspace give the equidistant points between two points joining linearly. Can I get the equidistant points along a line joining a set of points.

For Eg:

```
import numpy as np
npts = 10
xcoords, ycoords = [0,1], [0,1]
xquery = np.linspace(xcoords[0],xcoords[1], npts)
yquery = np.linspace(ycoords[0],ycoords[1], npts)
```

Here I need equidistant query points on the line joining a set of points

```
xcoords, ycoords = [0,1,5,8], [0,3,6,7]
```

Comment: So, you need equidistant 4D points between the 2 4D points you specified? Like a grid?

Comment: Sorry if it is not clear. They are just 2D points (0,0),(1,3),(5,6) and (8,7). I want to get equidistant points along the line joining the above 2D points. Similar to the one done using QGIS here(https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27102/creating-equidistant-points-in-qgis).

Comment: You are looking for a implemented solution (I don't know none) or you want to implement it yourself?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Subdivision of a 2D segmented line in parts of equal lenght :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import numpy as np


x = [0, 1, 8, 2, 2]
y = [1, 0, 6, 7, 2]

# Linear length on the line
distance = np.cumsum(np.sqrt( np.ediff1d(x, to_begin=0)**2 + np.ediff1d(y, to_begin=0)**2 ))
distance = distance/distance[-1]

fx, fy = interp1d( distance, x ), interp1d( distance, y )

alpha = np.linspace(0, 1, 15)
x_regular, y_regular = fx(alpha), fy(alpha)

plt.plot(x, y, 'o-');
plt.plot(x_regular, y_regular, 'or');
plt.axis('equal');
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thank you very much @xdze2. Your answer solved my question and will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: To clarify that this answer only provides equidistant points in x direction. My misinterpretation of the question

I believe what you are looking for is interpolation?
The documentation for scipy.interpolate is here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.0.0/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d

But to quickly show for your example:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
x=[0,1,5,8]
y=[0,3,6,7]
f=interp1d(x,y)
```

then just enter your new x points you wish to query into f like so (xnew cannot exceed the min/max bounds of x)

```
xnew=np.linspace(0,8,10)
ynew=f(xnew)
```

and to have a look just plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(xnew,ynew,'ro',x,y,'x')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes, we can do interpolation but it doesn't give equidistant points along line. From your solution the distance between first two red circle points is large than that of the next two red points.

Comment: Oh I see. Yeah the interpolation I did will be equidistant in x but not y